# dynamic checkboxes handle in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here i tried many ways to get the values from the dynamic generated chekcboxes in react js but i failed, help me to solve this issues..
am getting the problems like

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined" 
or anyone of the states like "{Name: "Module2",View:false,Create:false,Edit:false,Delete:false}",
```

the values should be update in the handlechange itself.

```
const DynamicCB = ()=>{
const modules = ["Module1", "Module2","Module3"]
const [state,setState] = useState([{
    Name:'',
    View:false,
    Create:false,
    Edit:false,
    Delete:false
}])

const handlechange = (name ,i) =>event=>{

    console.log(name)

    const Data=[...state] 
    if(Data.includes(event.target.name)){    
        Data[i][name] = event.target.checked
        setState(state,Data) 
    }else{
        Data[i].Name = event.target.name
        Data[i][name] = event.target.checked
        setState(state,Data);
    }


  return(<>
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <h2>Modules</h2>
        </div>
        {
            modules.map((item,i)=>(
                <div className="row" key={i}>
                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <h4>{item}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <input type="checkbox" name={item} className="m-2" 
                            onChange={handlechange('View',i)}/>View
                        <input type="checkbox" name={item} className="m-2" 
                            onChange={handlechange('Create',i)}/>Create
                        <input type="checkbox" name={item} className="m-2" 
                            onChange={handlechange('Edit',i)}/>Edit
                        <input type="checkbox" name={item} className="m-2" 
                            onChange={handlechange('Delete',i)}/>Delete 
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))
        }     
    </div>
  </>)
}
```

in my try it shows any one of the below array of object or, it shows an error like "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Name')".
i need the state values like as below

```
[
   { Name: "Module1",View:true,Create:false,Edit:false,Delete:false},
   { Name: "Module2",View:false,Create:false,Edit:false,Delete:false},
   { Name: "Module3",View:false,Create:true,Edit:true,Delete:false}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the `state` (using the `useState` callback) and update each module state using `moduleName` and the operation name ("View", "Edit", "Create", "Delete")like below.

```
  const modules = ["Module1", "Module2", "Module3"];
  const [state, setState] = useState(() =>
    modules.map((module) => {
      return {
        Name: module,
        View: false,
        Create: false,
        Edit: false,
        Delete: false
      };
    })
  );

  const handlechange = (name, i) => (event) => {
    const moduleName = event.target.name;
    const actionName = name;

    setState((prev) => {
      return prev.map((module) => {
        if (module.Name === moduleName) {
          return { ...module, [actionName]: event.target.checked };
        }
        return module;
      });
    });
  };
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cloud-2djny?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Prasanth, check this out !!

Comment: @Prasanth, can you please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue?

Comment: Amila Senadheera, te code is working.. wow..thak you